# Extend AngularJS form object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to extend angular's `FormController` object? I simply want to add a method that I'd be able to call in my views.

eg:

```
// pseudo 'decorator' code
FormController.prototype.myMethod = function () {};

// view:
<form name="myForm">
    <button ng-click="myForm.myMethod()">Do it!</button>
</form>
```

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried that? I expect you can use actual [decorators as describe on the AngularJS site](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I tried that. Unfortunately, it does not work with controllers.